# How can i convert the date and time from Fri Sep 08 09:33:00 GMT+05:30 2017 to "08-09-2017 09:33"

Tags: android

I tried to convert time from Fri Sep 08 09:33:00 GMT+05:30 2017 to "08-09-2017 09:33" in android but i get the output like this 08-09-2017 04:03 here time is not getting correctly..below i write my code please solve it thank you.

String dateTime = "Fri Sep 08 09:33:00 GMT+05:30 2017"

DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "E MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

```
    Date dateone = null;

    try {
        dateone = inputFormat.parse(dateTime);

        DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm",
                Locale.ENGLISH);
        outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        dateTimeForUpdate = outputFormat.format(dateone);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting timezone to `UTC` and `04:03` is the correct time for this timezone. If you want to get time in your (+05:30) timezone, set it to `DateFormat` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
    outputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
    dateTimeForUpdate = outputFormat.format(dateone);
    System.out.println(dateTimeForUpdate);
```